# Can not access request data from ajax post request in symfony 3

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, post, request

I am using symfony 3.4 and I would like to send some data to controller but I do not know why I can not access it like it is show in symfony documentation:

This is my js function:

```
function sendQuantitiesToController() {

// Validate data
var validation = validateQuestionnaireReviewFormData();
if (validation === false) {
    return false;
}
// Get form data
var data = getReviewFormComponentsData();
var id = document.getElementById('questionnaire-id').innerText;

// Send data 
$.post("http://localhost:8000/questionnaire/"+id+"/review", {
    components:              data.components,
    optional_components:     data.optional_components
},
function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

}

And this is my Controller function:

```
/**
 * Questionnaire result review
 *
 * @Route("/questionnaire/{id}/review", name="_questionnaire_review", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function questionnaireReviewAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(ResultOverviewType::class, $result);
    $contactForm = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {            
        // Get data from request 
        $components = $request->request->get('components');
        $optionalComponents = $request->request->get('optional_components');
        ...
        }  
    }

    return [
        'form'              => $form->createView(),
        'contactForm'       => $contactForm->createView(),
        'questionnaire'     => $questionnaire
    ];
}
```

Twig Template:

```
{{ form_start(contactForm, {'attr': {'onsubmit': 'return sendQuantitiesToController();'}}) }}           
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(contactForm) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

The problem is that the $request->request->get('components') in controller is always null, but I checked getReviewFormComponentsData() with console.log and there is data there so the problem is probably with ajax post request. What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

To get request data from ajax request in Symfony Controller you should simply do that:

```
public function questionnaireReviewAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(ResultOverviewType::class, $result);
    $contactForm = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {            
        // Get data from request 
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        $components = $data['components'];
        $optionalComponents = $data['optional_components'];
        ...
    }
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but this is not he case. The problem is that $request->getContent() or $request->request do not have components or optional_components data inside. For some reason the data is not send with ajax request. But I don't know why.

Comment: You should check your browser console to get the errors., plus debugging with console. Log

Comment: There is no error. I try run in console seprate functions and if I run the ajax post part it works! but if I call functions onsubmit (on button) for some reason do not work. Also post params are empty. If I run in console function the ajax request params are there like it shoul be! So problems is form call here: {{ form_start(contactForm, {'attr': {'onsubmit': 'return sendQuantitiesToController();'}}) }}

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused. try console.log(data.components) and console.log(data.optional_components) just before $.post(...). Are they empty?

Comment: No. they are not empty. But when I check after the request has been proccessed with symfony profiler it shows that there are no post and get parameters...So no data with request. I do not get it.

Comment: Have you used $data = $request->getContent(); $data = json_decode($data, true); in you symfony controller?